# Creating a one to many relation between a model and strings in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a join table between an ActiveRecord model and strings such that the model can have many strings.  My join table is:

```
create_table :project_structures_sku_prefixes, id:false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :project_structure, foreign_key: true
  t.string :sku_prefix
end
```

I'm not sure how I would declare this in my model.  Something like:

```
has_many_and_belongs_to :sku_prefixes, class_name:'String'
```

Can this be accomplished in Rails without having to create another simple model that just stores a string?

Comment: Depending on which database you are using then using an actual array type column might be a good option. But I think you would get better answers if you provide some detail on the real world problem that this code is supposed to solve and not just how you imagine it should be solved.

Comment: I'd have a look at the *has_and_belongs_to_many* association (see link). That being said, associating with plain strings is not really possible without hacky Rails code and probably not what you want. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association